# input-group with two text inputs and one button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I have now is one input text and button beside it:

```
<form id="chat-form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input name="message" id="message" type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">send</button>
        </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3mgycoop/

I'd like have two inputs and button beside in. All in one line like so:

```
[         product        ][    price    ][ send-btn]
```

And it should it be 100% wide, just like I have now.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a few `ids` to your elements and add the following css:

```
#message{
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}
#message2{
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/3mgycoop/2/